# Problems changing the content of a paragraph within a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, paragraph

I'm fairly new to html and Javascript (I'm taking a web design class atm) but I'm a good programmer (experienced in c#, c++, visual basic, java, and a few others) and I'm fairly good at debugging stuff. Now onto the good stuff =).

I'm trying to change the text content of a paragraph tag that is inside of a table. Here's where it gets fun. I'm trying to do it by the user selecting a cell from the dropdown then entering text into a textfield, then finally pressing a button to set it. I have the values of the choices in the dropdown exactly the same as the ids of the paragraphs within the cells. When you hit the button it stores (theoretically haven't been able to try it) the value of the selected item in the dropdown and the text in the textfield, then sets the html inside the paragraph (with .innerHtml) to the text in the textbox. it uses the var that I stored the selected option in as the  id in the `.getElementId()` call and the text var as what to set it to. I do not know if there's anything else to explain, so here's the entire htm file with the Javascript included.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Table Pg 1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY background="http://www.pptbackgrounds.net/uploads/elegant-grey-illumination-background-presentations-powerpoint-backgrounds.jpg" link="#FF00FF" alink="#9900FF" vlink="#0000FF" text="#00FF00">
    <SCRIPT>
        var tableOneBorder = 1;

        function incBorder()
        {
            tableOneBorder = tableOneBorder + 1;

            document.getElementById("tab1").setAttribute("border", tableOneBorder);
        }

        function decBorder()
        {
            if(tableOneBorder > 0)
            {
                tableOneBorder = tableOneBorder - 1;
            }

            document.getElementById("tab1").setAttribute("border", tableOneBorder);
        }

        function changeContent()
        {
            var cell = document.getElementById("dropDown")[document.getElementById("dropDown").selectedIndex].value;
            var text = document.getElementById("textField").value;

            document.getElementById(cell).innerHtml = text;
        }

    </SCRIPT>
    <BUTTON onclick="decBorder()">Decrease Border</BUTTON>    <BUTTON onclick="incBorder()">Increase Border</BUTTON>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    Enter text, select cell, and click 'Change' to change a cell:
    <INPUT type="text" id="textField"/>  
    <select id="dropDown">
        <option value="a1">A1</option>
        <option value="a2">A2</option>
        <option value="a3">A3</option>
        <option value="a3">A4</option>

        <option value="b1">B1</option>
        <option value="b2">B2</option>
        <option value="b3">B3</option>
        <option value="a3">B4</option>

        <option value="c1">C1</option>
        <option value="c2">C2</option>
        <option value="c3">C3</option>
        <option value="a3">C4</option>
    </select>
         <BUTTON onclick="changeContent()">Change Text</BUTTON>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <TABLE id="tab1" border="1" width="80%" align="center" wrap="hard">
    <TR height="100"> <TD><P align="center" id="a1">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="a2">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="a3">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="a4">TEST</P></TD></TR>
    <TR height="100"> <TD><P align="center" id="b1">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="b2">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="b3">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="b4">TEST</P></TD></TR>
    <TR height="100"> <TD><P align="center" id="c1">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="c2">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="c3">TEST</P></TD> <TD><P align="center" id="c4">TEST</P></TD></TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine..Just a silly mistake..:)
Do replace 'innerHtml' with 'innerHTML' like this in below:

> document.getElementById(cell).innerHTML = text;

Learn more about that in this link.. [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

You can also use 'textContent', in case of no HTML content required..

Comment: OMG, thanks. You know whats really funny?
I used that because of my research into fixing it. Apparently i skipped over 3 capitals -_-

Comment: @KillerOfPie Your lab teacher was not able to tell you that??.. :D

Comment: Haha..Happened a lot with me too.. :)..Although you can accept it as an answer.. ;)

Comment: Unfortunatly Javascript loves to stop every single time it's like "Oh, no. He didn't really mean that, did he?"

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar in his defense he only looked at it for a few seconds...im not usually the person in the class that needs help. this hole thing was more then i needed to do, our class hasn't even gotten into javascript yet. and it makes me wait a couple minutes before i can accept it =)